# Excel - Difference between two excel files with one sheet?

Tags: excel, list

I have 2 excel files. This contain changes on a couple of rows. I would like to withdraw the changes done.

What I have tried is that I tried concating all the columns, and then counting how many time this has occured. IF it matches first sheet of second i will call it a change.

Basically --> Concat --> unique --> countif on both sheets --> is it same on both sheet? If one is bigger, which tells me if i added or deleted rows...

The purpose of doing this is that I have a BOM. No specific identifiers, but just a BOM. This can mean that i can have duplicates and so on. I want to get out the different rows. For example if I removed 3 rows from first bom but added 1 other row, i want to extract it.

I have tried doing this, and it quickly becomes to advanced for me. Are there any functions I can use that makes my life easier? :) Coding in Visual basic is not my strong side...

Comment: Perhaps you can share what you have coded?

Comment: Hi, I haven't written any code. All I have done is using excel.

=TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,Table3[@[Column1]:[ERP number]])
Then I used another sheet to make them UNIQUE and count them up in the list. Then I compare the list to eachother and can guess which one is new and which one is deleted. :)

Comment: Your question has an edit link at the bottom of it. Can you add screenshots of these two sheets to your question? Only include the important information so that the cells are more easily seen in the image. Can you explain how you know which is new and which is deleted as you wrote above? If I understand how you guess, then I might be able to better understand how to resolve it in formula etc.